# How to POST via REST a correct markup to a confluence page?

Tags: json, rest, python-3.x, confluence, confluence-rest-api

How to post topic in correct wiki syntax when body has "\r\n" which means "carriage return" and "newline"?

When I use data=json.dumps(%topic_body%) it makes all my text with literally "\r\n" in it!

Of course text formatted like this - cannot be used as wiki formatted on confluence!

This is an example of usual markup:

```
h1. Some Description
[Some link|Link...] is ...

h2. Some

h2. Some Versions
* 9
*  10
*  11

h1. Some Software 

||Table 1 ||Block 1||Some||Some 2||
```

This is how it reproduces via json:

```
{"storage": {"value": "b'h1. Some Description\\r\\n[Some link|Link...] is ...\\r\\n\\r\\nh2. Some\\r\\n\\r\\nh2. Some Versions\\r\\n* 9\\r\\n*  10\\r\\n*  11\\r\\n\\r\\nh1. Some Software \\r\\n\\r\\n||Table 1 ||Block 1||Some||Some 2||'", "representation": "wiki"}}}
```

This is important, and I can't send body in markdown because my confluence did not understand this way of macros:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="attachments">
</ac:structured-macro>
```

So I need to send my topic body that way, which can include new line method (https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-wiki-markup-251003035.html)

Also I can't use documented:

> Explicitly, by entering two consecutive backslashes:  \\

Because in this condition wiki markup make all text the same forematted, just like:

```
h1. Some Description \\ \\ [Some link|Link...] is ...
```

This whole string will be "h1." size. All all other text from this string will be formatted as h1, ignoring any other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!
You can ignore the case, when visual(in browser) wiki markdown does not work for you. It will work via REST anyway!

Comment: The secret sauce is "representation": "wiki". Thank you! I kept using 'storage' for some reason, and it just uses the payload as plain text.